# White smoke coming out of manual locking hub

Tags: dodge, truck

Alright so I just bought a 1988 Dodge W100 5.9 360 small block. I got it home a over a hours drive didn’t notice anything strange but the next day after driving it about a hour I noticed hearing some screeching noises coming from the passenger side. It wasn’t to noticeable and after awhile it went away. But later on it felt like the truck got yanked all of a sudden and my brake pedal got spongy. I got it home to find the manual locking hub cap is missing with white smoke rolling out and almost no brakes. Pedal goes almost straight to the floor before stopping. Have no clue to what this could be because haven’t heard of this exact problem. Lastest thing I tried driving it around the my block and the clunks is getting worse. Also have to add because might have something to do with this it has large mud tires and a lifted suspension. Thanks for any help! Would rather fix myself if possible

Comment: How about more information on the locking hub cap missing and the white smoke?  That, to me, sounds like a big problem that lies at the root of the other problems you've mentioned. Smoke coming from the axle is not normal!

Comment: Disassemble and inspect the locking hub and wheel bearings.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was thinking the same thing it really has me puzzled. Also want to add that on the side that’s smoking gets burning hot. I just about burnt my fingers touching the hub. But I touched the rim around it and it was fine it I figure something is very wrong! I just don’t get what’s going on about the brakes unless it’s two separate problems. Also wanting to add I’d already have the wheel off but I don’t have a jack big enough to get her off the ground. :(

Comment: To add a update I got the tire off and the wheel bearing is bad. Also burnt brake pads. Brake is sticking to the rotor also. Not good.